# Memory leak with glfwSetWindowTitle?

Tags: opengl, c++, memory, glfw

I am using GLFW for a game, and I have a function which allows me to set the window title.

```
    // PROBLEM WITH INCREASING MEMORY USAGE
    void WindowSystem::setTitle( const string & title )
    {

        glfwSetWindowTitle( window, title.c_str() );

    }
```

This function is called once during every iteration of the main program loop, so that I can have a basic FPS counter. Under Xcode the program memory usage increases faster and faster. If I replace title.c_str() with a literal, the problem does not happen, i.e., the following does not cause the same memory usage growth.

```
        // DOESN'T CAUSE PROBLEM
        void WindowSystem::setTitle( const string & title )
        {

            glfwSetWindowTitle( window, "Hello world!" );

        }
```

This where the function is called.

```
    int SystemControl::update()
    {
        double time = glfwGetTime();
        double timeStep = time - control->lastUpdate;
        control->lastUpdate = time;

        float frameRate = 1.0f / timeStep;

        string windowTitle = std::to_string( frameRate );

        control->windowSystem->setTitle( windowTitle );

        control->physicsSystem->update( timeStep );

        return OK;
    }
```

The string title is allocated on the stack, and should be freed at the end of update. Could there possibly be a memory leak? I understand that the pointer for c_str() is internally managed, and does not need to be freed.

Comment: Could it be that the string literal allows compiler optimization, but the string that I am passing to the function never returns memory back to the OS? Another note: this makes initially about a 10 Mb difference, from 37 Mb, in program footprint, then it rapidly goes off past 200 Mb in about 2 minutes.

Comment: and if you pass the string as a const ref?

Comment: Note that title.c_str()  could be invalid (dangling pointer) when you release title. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/ or http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/29153/ for more detail)

Comment: By the way, if working in visual studio, have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx for tracking memory leaks

Comment: Consider looking at the source and/or reporting an issue with the library.

Comment: My bet would be you are allocating the string on heap and not freeing it, and when you pass literal the compiler optimizes the parameter out as well as the allocation because the string is no longer (ever) used. But only wild guess - the important part of the code is missing here, moreover OP does not even tried to look for *leaks* - the footprint hardly tells anything.